# Convert date (different formats) to day in r

Tags: r

I have a dateset with different date formats (e.g., Nov. 24, 2014 & 7-Jul-14)

I tried `as.Date(thd$SubmitDate, "%B. %d, %Y")`, but it seems that this is not enough.

Comment: Check out R's [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) package. It's a life-saver when dealing with dates. Your two examples seem like they'd fit well with the mdy and dmy parsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(v1, guess_formats(v1, c('mdY', 'dmy')))
#[1] "2014-11-24 UTC" "2014-07-07 UTC"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('Nov.24, 2014', '7-Jul-14')
```

Comment: Now my data only has 7-Jul-14 as date format. But now it is showing me as character, and I used the following code trying to convert it to date but failed. Could you kindly tell me why.                                     date = thread$submitdate
date = as.Date(date, "%d-%b-%y")

Comment: @facebook-644909588975213  Have you checked the `str` or the `?class` of the column. If your date only has `7-Jul-14` , your code should work `v1 <- as.Date('7-Jul-14', '%d-%b-%y');v1#[1] "2014-07-07"; str(v1)#
 Date[1:1], format: "2014-07-07"`